# Whenever i try to create a voice connection in discord.js it says "error: adapterCreator is not a function"

Tags: discord, discord.js, voice

So i try  creating a discord.js voice connection like so:

```
connection = joinVoiceChannel({
   channelId: <myChannel'sId>,
   guildId: <myGuild'sId>,
   adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});
```

Just like it is shown in the discord.js guide but it doesn't work, and no matter what data i give adapterCreator, it always gives: "error: adapterCreator is not a function".
I am totally lost and stuck, please help me, i couldn't find any documentation on this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBs53.png)

Comment: According to the error the code you have provided isn't your actual code. The code you have provided in the question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this actually fixes it, but it fixes something:

You gotta remove the comma after the last entry.

```
adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
//Becomes:
adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
```

Comment: Trailing commas are no problem in JavaScript (they are in JSON) and get ignored.